# Add-Member inside an outside foreach loop not exporting iterations to CSV

Tags: powershell, foreach, hashtable

**Input:**

Servers: [1,2,3]
Services: [a,b,c]

The Server 1 has Service "a"
The Server 2 has Service "a", "b"
The Server 3 has Service "b", "c"

Expected output in CSV (gave correct output on console):

```
Server_Name ServerAvailability ServiceName[0] ServiceStatus[0] ServiceName[1] ServiceStatus[1]
1 Up a Running
2 Up a Running b Running
3 Up b Running c Running
```

Actual output in CSV:

```
Server_Name ServerAvailability ServiceName[0] ServiceStatus[0] ServiceName[1] ServiceStatus[1]
1 Up a Running
2 Up a Running
3 Up b Running
```

```
foreach ($s in $servers) {
    foreach ($srv in $services) {
        $Asrv = Get-Service -Name $srv -ComputerName $s
        if ($Asrv -ne $null) {
            $HashSrvs.Add($Asrv.Name, $Asrv.Status)
        }
    }

    $infoObject = @()
    $infoObject = New-Object PSObject
    $infoObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server name" -Value $s
    $infoObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerAvailability" -Value $ConStatus

    $i=0

    foreach ($key in $HashSrvs.GetEnumerator()) {
        $infoObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceName[$i]" -Value $key.Key -Force
        $infoObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServiceStatus[$i]" -Value $key.Value -Force
        $i++
    }
    $infoColl += $infoObject
}
$infoColl | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\Server_Inventory_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -Encoding UTF8
```

The output is correct. No error shown. The error occurs at the CSV file. The highlighted `foreach` loop is not iterated. It stops at `Service Name[0]` and `Service Status[0]`. Please help me with this.

Comment: Edit your question to include 1) an example of your incorrect output and 2) an example of the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how `Export-Csv` works. The cmdlet takes a list of objects as input and determines the columns for the CSV from the first object in that list. For all subsequent objects missing properties are filled with null values and additional properties are omitted.

To get the result you want you'd need to know the maximum number of services and add that number of properties to each object. Alternatively you could create the CSV manually by building a list of comma-separated strings and writing that via `Set-Content` or `Out-File`. Both is doable, of course, but a much simpler, much more straightforward approach would be putting the list of services into a single column with a different delimiter:

```
$infoColl = foreach ($s in $servers) {
    $svc = Get-Service -Name $services -Computer $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
           ForEach-Object { '{0}={1}' -f ($_.Name, $_.Status) }

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Server name'        = $s
        'ServerAvailability' = $ConStatus
        'Services'           = $svc -join '|'
    }
}
```